# Почему не работает модуль pyperclip в Pycharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программирую всего 2 недели, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Установил pyperclip используя командную строку и pip.[image: установка с командной строки] pyperclip работает в стандартной IDLE.[image: вывод в стандартной IDLE] Далее создал новый проект в Pycharm, при импорте модуль виден, но тот же код не дает никаких результатов.[image: тот же код в Pycharm] Не пойму, если Pycharm видит модуль, почему он не работает?[image: настройки проекта]Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле все у вас работает, просто IDLE в интерактивном режиме автоматически выводит результат выполнения строки кода (как и любой другой [REPL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL)), но если тот же код запускать из файла (в том числе и в IDLE), автоматического вывода не будет.

Вам нужно добавить вывод полученного значения, например, через `print`:

```
print(pyperclip.paste())
```